# Tensorflow sequence-to-sequence LSTM within LSTM (nested)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, word-embedding

I would like to build an LSTM with a special word embedding, but I have some questions about how this would work.

As you might know, some LSTMs operate on characters, so it is characters in, characters out. I would like to do the same, with an abstraction on words to learn a robust embedding on them with a nested LSTM to be resistant to slight character-level errors.

So, a tiny LSTM would unroll on every letter of a word, then this would create an embedding of the word. Each embedded word in a sentence would then be fed as an input to a higher level LSTM, which would operate on a word level at every time step, rather than on characters.

Questions:
- I cannot find anymore the research paper that talked about that. If you know of what I talk about, I would like to put a name on what I want to do. 
- Does some TensorFlow open-source code already exist for that?
- Else, do you have an idea on how to implement that? The output of the neural network might be harder to deal with, as we would need to undo the word embedding for the training on characters with an output nested LSTM. The whole thing should be trained once as a single unit (workflow: LSTM chars in, LSTM on words, LSTM chars out).

I guess that `rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell` would stack LSTMs on top of each other rather than nesting them.

Else would you recommend training the embeddings (in and out) as an autoencoder outside the main LSTM ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the paper you are referring to.

But here is an idea on how I would implement something like this in TensorFlow:

You can create 2 [LSTMCells](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L243).

If you want to support a variable number of characters per word and a variable number of words per sequence you can copy and adapt the code for the dynamic_rnn (see rnn.py)
Instead of a single while loop you would create a nested while loop. The inner one operating on characters calling the first LSTMCell and resetting the state after each word. The outer one operating on embedded words (the output from the inner loop) and calling the second LSTMCell.

Typically, whether or not you should train embeddings separately depends on how much data you have available. If you don't have a lot of data training an embedding separately (on a potentially different dataset) may make sense. If you can afford to and your model is training well, then training the embedding along with your whole network can have benefits because the meaning of characters can be task-specific.

But I'm wondering how this approach compares to first doing spelling correction and then using a standard word embedding. Then you can use some of the [standard embedding tools](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/contrib.framework.html#safe_embedding_lookup_sparse) and a single LSTMCell with the dynamic_rnn.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably talking about [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.02096.pdf). They don't seem to have released their code..

I don't think you would have to "undo the word embedding", because you can do the training simultaneously on two objectives :

- For each word, one loss for the characters produced, with respect to the true characters of the word. CE loss looks good for this.
- One loss for the "word embeddings" produced in the decoder (by the inner LSTM), with respect to the word embeddings produced in the encoder (by the outer LSTM applied on characters). I'm thinking MSE loss for example.

(Does it make sense?)

Out of curiosity, did you manage to implement this idea ? I'm going to try it in Pytorch